# distribute rest space in two container beside a fixed width container

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have three container, `left`, `middle` and `right`. Width ratio is like 15%, 70% and 15%. I want to restrict max-width of middle container to 1000px.

This works fine as long as screen resolution is under 1428px. If screen resolution is greater than 1428px, 70% becomes greater than 1000px. So i need to write another rule for these bigger screen.

So middle container is now 1000px. How i can distribute rest space to other two container - `left` and `right`? A JavaScript solution gives a certain jump/shake in the browser. I want to avoid these shaking in browser.

Comment: maybe something like `width:calc( (100vw - 1000px) / 2);` I suppose this is what you want but http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc here is browser support for the rule :)

Answer (score 1):

OK so here is how things are. I suppose you have html something like this :

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="center"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

So you have to apply css like this ( I don't know if you're satisfied with browser support but I think there is no css only another way)

CSS:

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.left,.right,.center{
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
.left,.right{
width:15%;
background:yellow;
}
.center{
  background:red;
  width:70%;
  max-width:1000px;
}
@media(min-width:1000px){
  .left,.right{
    width:calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2)
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lghms68y/ Here is a fiddle. NOTE : You'll have to zoom out the page to see the effect :)